# how can I handle exception in firestore flutter?

Tags: flutter, exception, google-cloud-firestore, error-handling, try-catch

I try in many ways to handle exception in firestore but I can't ,
please help?
[suppose in line 127 i catch the error and show it in screen as showsnackbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wjbl.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

**Simple Solution**

```
 ElevatedButton(
 onPressed:()async{
   if(_globalKey.currenState!.validate()){
  try{
  QuerySnapshot querSnapshot=await 
  FirebaseFirestore.collection("admin").doc("adminLogin").get();
  if(querySnapshot.docs.isNotEmpty){
    querySnapshot.docs.forEach((element){
       if (element.data(['adminEmail'] == email && element.data()? 
    ['adminPassword'] ==password) { 
    ScaffoldMessenger.of (context).showSnackbar( const SnackBar(
   backgroundcolor: Colors.green, content: Text(
   'Login success', textAlign: TextAlign.center, )));

  Navigator.pushNamed (context, AdminScreen.id);
    });
 
  }
  }

  }catch(e){

  }
   }},
  
    
  child:Text("login"))
```